# Swift async method call for a command line app

Tags: swift, asynchronous, console-application

I'm trying to reuse some async marked code that works great in a SwiftUI application in a simple Swift-Command line tool.
Lets assume for simplicity that I'd like to reuse a function

```
func fetchData(base : String) async throws -> SomeDate
    {
        let request = createURLRequest(forBase: base)
        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw FetchError.urlResponse
        }
        let returnData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(SomeData.self, from: data)
        
        return returnData
    }
```

in my command line application.
A call like

```
    let allInfo = try clerk.fetchData("base")
```

in my "main-function" gives the error message `'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency`.
What is the correct way to handle this case.

Thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 10):

To call an `async` method the call must take place inside an `async` method or wrapped in a `Task`.
Further the method must be called wirh `await`

```
Task {
    do {
        let allInfo = try await clerk.fetchData("base")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

You can make the entry point of the CLI `async` with this syntax

```
@main
struct CLI {
    static func main() async throws {

        let args = CommandLine.arguments
        ...
}
```

The name of the struct is arbitrary.

You need to rename the file from `main.swift` to `CLI.swift` to fix the `error 'main' attribute cannot be used in a module that contains top-level code`.

Comment: The bit about making the tool's `main()` async is the part I did not know. (voted.) Where is that documented?

Comment: @DuncanC [HackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-make-async-command-line-tools-and-scripts) mentioned it. I don't know if it's documented somewhere in the Apple documentation.

Comment: Hi @vadian, 
thanks for the answer. The hint to the declaration of the main-function solves my problem.

Comment: Adding @main results with another error that you cannot put it in module containing top level code

Comment: `'main' attribute cannot be used in a module that contains top-level code`

Comment: @malhal Yes, you cannot use it in a Playground.

Comment: Hope you don't mind I figured out the fix and added a note to your answer, I'm sure it will help others.

Comment: Oh in case you didn't know, the new Command Line template no longer has `@main` so have to add it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Argument Parser framework then from version 1.0 it supports async context. You have to make your struct conforms to protocol AsyncParsableCommand. It creates context in which async function can be run safely.