# Swift CLI app 'main' attribute cannot be used in a module that contains top-level code

Tags: swift, async-await

I am trying to call functions from EventKit in a simple command line tool app. However, some of the functions are `async`, which results in `'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency`. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71298098/swift-async-method-call-for-a-command-line-app) but neither of the given solutions work.

Putting code inside `Task {}` never runs, and declaring a struct with a `static func main() async` function wont compile with the error `'main' attribute cannot be used in a module that contains top-level code`. I am trying to run a single file `test.swift` with the following content.

```swift
import Foundation
import EventKit

@main
struct Test {
    static func main() async {
        var reminders = EKEventStore.init()
        
        print("run")
        
        if EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.reminder) != EKAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
            do {
                var ok = try await reminders.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.reminder)
                print(ok)
            } catch {
                print("error")
                return
            }
        }
        print("authroized")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41):

At least for me, I had this issue when using `@main` in main.swift. I renamed main.swift to some random name and the error went away.

Comment: Apple state this to be the correct solution. See comment in another answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is a [bug in Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/55127). Running with `-parse-as-library` as an argument for the compiler makes it work.

Comment: Having further investigated, perhaps this is normal behaviour. See https://apple.github.io/swift-argument-parser/documentation/argumentparser/gettingstarted

"The Swift compiler uses either the type marked with \@main or a main.swift file as the entry point for an executable program. You can use either one, but not both — rename your main.swift file to the name of the command when you add \@main. In this case, rename the file to Count.swift.".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to do a clean build (removing any old outputs). I've deleted the 'main.swift' and replaced it with my own Swift-file and ran into this issue.

Cleaning the build directory did the trick for me.