# Alamofire's callback block cannot run, i'm sure the server received the request send by Alamofire

Tags: alamofire

Alamofire's callback block cannot run, i'm sure the server  received the request send by Alamofire
here‘s the code:

```
import Alamofire
import Foundation

@main
public struct SwiftClient {

    public static func main() {
        let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello"
        AF.request(url).response { response in
            debugPrint(response)
        }
        sleep(10)
    }
}
```

when i execute `swift run`, debugPrint doesn't run

Comment: It's a "script", so the program will end before the callback is called. Either use `async` (see https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-make-async-command-line-tools-and-scripts or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71298098/swift-async-method-call-for-a-command-line-app) or keep the "program alive" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944011/how-to-prevent-a-command-line-tool-from-exiting-before-asynchronous-operation-co

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a command line tool with `@main`, I suggest using the `async` form so you can use Alamofire's async APIs, it will be a much nicer experience.

```swift
@main
struct SwiftClient {
    static func main() async {
        let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello"
        let task = AF.request(url).serializingData()
        debugPrint(await task.response)
    }
}
```

If you're still not getting a response you can log your requests using an Alamofire `EventMonitor`, use a proxy tool like Proxyman, or a network inspector like Wireshark.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. Your code works good.  But i'm really curious why the callback in my code doesn't called.

Comment: Not sure. If your request was taking more than your `sleep` time, the process would have finished before your handler was called. With the await version it will stay alive exactly as long as necessary for the request to finish or timeout.

Comment: I start the service on the same device. I'm quite sure the sleep time is long enough. Even it sleep 100 seconds, the callback still not called.

Comment: Ah, it may also be that `dispatchMain()` wasn't called to start up the main run loop, which Alamofire calls its default completions on. I believe Swift concurrency starts that for you.